# jQuery works 3/4 times the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery function that takes a thumbnail tile generated by a plugin and then throw it elsewhere in the DOM. The function works half the time.

The reason I had to do it this way is because the plugin automatically renders half the HTML on page load AND because the CSS solution was terrible. I'd have to overflow containers into one another and it was just terrible hacky.

The plugin is a picture with thumbnails. Each time the thumbnails are clicked the corresponding photo is up in the main picture frame;

Code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('ol').append('<li data-toggle="modal" id="thumb" class="yt-thumb" overflow-scroll="false" overflow-scroll="true" data-target="#youtubeModal"><img src="/images/dome-thumb.jpg" /></li> '); // add youtube to thumb slider
  $('ol').appendTo( $('#thumb-area') )
 }, 2000);
```

The reason it is in a setTimout is it seems there is a delay in when the plugin generates the code. Unfortunately the plugin is part of an overall theme and I'm unable to post the code so vague ideas are welcome.

Comment: One vague idea is to look into using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for changes to the part of the DOM where the plugin generates its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the MutationObserver is probably the best approach.

Another way to handle it is to have a function that retries the transformation if the DOM isn't ready for you. Something like this:

```
function transformThumbnails(iteration) {
  if (iteration === undefined) {
    iteration = 0;
  }
  else if (iteration < 100) { // don’t retry forever
    var isReady = true; // TODO: test if DOM is ready for your transformation
     if (isReady) {
       $('ol').append('<li data-toggle="modal" id="thumb" class="yt-thumb" overflow-scroll="false" overflow-scroll="true" data-target="#youtubeModal"><img src="/images/dome-thumb.jpg" /></li> '); // add youtube to thumb slider
       $('ol').appendTo( $('#thumb-area') )
     }
     else {
       // not ready, so retry
       setTimeout(function(){transformThumbnails(iteration + 1);}, 100);
     }
  }
}
transformThumbnails(); // kick it off
```

Comment: I should have added the code. I did throw this in a $(document).ready function. I'd assume this tests the same or not?

Comment: Setting "isReady" is an exercise for you to implement. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Not sure how you would test for the plugin's completion.

And yes, this would have to be called after document.ready. The point of my post was to show how to implement a retry mechanism. I've used code like this in the past. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this had no effect. How would I implement a mutation observer? There doesn't seem to be much literature on mutation observer api.